# Функция возвращает promise

Tags: javascript

Пишу JS функцию, которая должна вернуть html код сайта. Внутри функции всё работает, переменная content содержит в себе html код, как надо. А если я пытаюсь присвоить какой-либо переменной значение этой функции, то получаю promise. Javascript только начал изучать, пока что логику не совсем понимаю

```
async function getData(){
    let response = await fetch('https://yandex.ru/');
    let content = await response.text();
    return content;
}

let data = getData();
```

Переменная data в итоге хранит promise вместо текста, хотя content выводится на консоль именно как текст. Как это исправить?

Comment: let data = getData().then()...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в этом случае `data` останется Promise

Comment: @Grundy опять все эти заморочки с оборачиванием в функцию async надо делать?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, конечно :-) если ты попал в async - из него не выбраться :)

Comment: Async-await  это за кулисами promise/then. Суть в том, что только через  promise  вы можете ждать ответа и двигаться дальше с его напудствующими методами типа  then. Когда вы пишите  async  бейбел по умному и супер сложно оборачивает в промис, а await  оборачивает в then. Вы пишите простую конструкцию, а за кулисами это целая оптимизированная и умная штука, куда лучше даже не лезть. Но когда вы получаете код через promise, дальнейшее его выполнение может быть только там иначе вы получите пустой результат.

Comment: Спасибо большое!